# CROSS APPLY in MERGE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cross-apply, sql-merge

There is a table where values in multiple columns need to be corrected. Then there is a table containing all values which need to be corrected.

Is there a simple way how to use CROSS APPLY in MERGE statement?

With my current knowledge I would need to run following code for column1, column2 and so on.

```
MERGE INTO target_table AS t
USING source_table AS s
ON t.key_column = s.key_column
    AND 'column_1' = s.correction_column
WHEN MATCHED THEN  
UPDATE SET t.column_1 = s.correction_value;
```

EDIT:
These are toy examples of the target, source and expected result.

Target:

```
##    |  uid | col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | col_4 | col_5
----------------------------------------------------
## 1  |    1 |     a |     a |     a |     a |     a
## 2  |    2 |     a |     a |     a |     a |     a
## 3  |    3 |     a |     a |     a |     a |     a
## 4  |    4 |     a |     a |     a |     a |     a
## 5  |    5 |     a |     a |     a |     a |     a
## 6  |    6 |     a |     a |     a |     a |     a
```

Source:

```
##    |  uid |   col | value
----------------------------
## 1  |    1 | col_1 |     B
## 2  |    1 | col_2 |     C
## 3  |    4 | col_3 |     D
## 4  |    4 | col_4 |     E
## 5  |    5 | col_3 |     F
```

Expected result:

```
##    |  uid | col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | col_4 | col_5
----------------------------------------------------
## 1  |    1 |     B |     C |     a |     a |     a
## 2  |    2 |     a |     a |     a |     a |     a
## 3  |    3 |     a |     a |     a |     a |     a
## 4  |    4 |     a |     a |     D |     E |     a
## 5  |    5 |     a |     a |     F |     a |     a
## 6  |    6 |     a |     a |     a |     a |     a
```

Comment: Where are you looking to put the `CROSS APPLY` exactly? What are you `CROSS APPLY`ing too, a table value function? Help us help you. Sample data and expected results will help with that too.

Comment: I agree with @Larnu, we need more information in order to assist here. As a side note, when using a `MERGE` statement, my target table is listed as just the table and my source table is typically a query. If it is a complicated query (or you need to filter on partitioned / windowed fields), then you can use `CTE` leading up to the `MERGE` statement.

Comment: I have added sample data and expected result. I do not have any table-valuee function for this. Maybe I am wrong about CROSS APPLY, but I thought that it is the function to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a query in parenthesis to create a derived table

Example

```
MERGE INTO target_table AS t
USING (select * from source_table a cross apply (select top 1 * from other_table b where b.id = a.id order by some_date desc) b2) AS s
ON t.key_column = s.key_column
    AND 'column_1' = s.correction_column
WHEN MATCHED THEN  
UPDATE SET t.column_1 = s.correction_value;
```

Comment: What would be the other_table? I think this does not solve the problem of applying the MERGE through all columns of target_table. Maybe my edit helps to understand the problem.